# how the evernote track the location of the source when voice or sound is recorded

Tags: android

I want to know  how the evernote app tracking the location when the voice or sound is recorded in. how the gprs works in tracking the user location in evernote kind of app in smart phones.

Comment: have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6695278/2219600)