# Is there any way to get the current location of a user and display it on a map without the need of GPS?

Tags: android, dictionary, gps, location, android-maps

I want an image of my user's location to show up on a map every time he/she logs in - and to only update the location after the user exits the app then reopens it. While he is in the page with the map the location should stay constant.

Can I achieve this without GPS? I haven't been able to find much about it online.

Thanks in advance for any insight

Comment: yes.You can get the user location based on Network Provider.Instead of using GPS_PROVIDER in LocationManager use NETWORK_PROVIDER.but it will give location of  the user approximately. if you need it accurately you need to use GPS_PROVIDER

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694391/android-get-current-location-of-user-without-using-gps-or-internet) where it's explained how to use network instead of GPS

Answer (score 0):

If you have the users IP addresses then you should be able to get the location of the IP by using a service (e.g. https://www.iplocation.net/). But this location is of course not very accurate especially for example when users are located for example in country A but use a VPN in country B (then the location inside country B will be shown to you) but it may be suitable for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Skyhook](http://www.skyhookwireless.com/) is what you are looking for.